CORS violation occuring in safari, but not chrome
I have a react web app that makes calls to an express web server.
When I access the web app in chrome, everything works as expected.
When I access the web app in safari, I get an error:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://subdomain.example.com/path due to access control checks.

In the network tab, I see the failed call:
Summary
URL: https://api.example.com/path
Status: —
Source: —
Initiator: 
2.6ac8194f.chunk.js:2:223735

Request
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Authorization: Bearer [...]
Origin: https://app.example.com
Referer: https://app.example.com/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.5 Safari/605.1.15

Response
No response headers

Googling suggests this is a CORS error. My express api sets up cors using the npm package:
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

(async () => {
    app.use(cors());

    app.use('/path', [
       require('./apis/path'),
    ]);

}()



This article explained that safari has stricter CORS policies that chrome, and that you can't use wildcards and must include the schema. So I tried to specify allowed origins:
app.use(cors({ origin: ['https://app.example.com', 'https://other-app.example.com'] }));

The error stayed the same.
Is there something else I'm missing?

also please note that when specifying the origin url please make sure to pass the url of the react app, e.g. if your react app is running on http://localhost:3000 then you'll do it this way app.use(cors({ origin: ['http://localhost:3000'] }));

You should perhaps try setting CORS headers for different responses. For example: header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT,DELETE,PATCH"); or header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");

@Thinkr Contrary to popular belief, Origin never needs to be listed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

@Bethany. The article (specifically its claims about Safari's lack of support for wildcards) is imprecise/outdated. Note that the root cause of their issue was actually a lack of CORS-configuration validation.

@Bethany What do you see in Safari's Network tab? Was a preflight request (it would use OPTIONS as its method) issued by the browser? If so, does it contain an Access-Control-Request-Headers header? If so, are all the values listed in that header also listed in the response's  Access-Control-Allow-Headers header?

@jub0bs I don't think it's making a preflight request. In chrome I see two different requests, the first OPTIONS and the second GET, but in safari I only see one request, which is red but has no status or method. I've edited the question to include the full output.

@Bethany Actually, Safari doesn't display preflight requests like Chrome does: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213215. This makes debugging CORS issues in Safari hard.

@jups0bs Right ok. Looking at the logs from the server, I see the GET and OPTIONS request from chrome, but nothing at all from when I load the page in safari. So maybe it can't hit the server at all, and the cors stuff is just a red herring.

Hi, As the request works in Chrome, it can be used as a solution to refer.
Therefore please post the two request headers (if possible ) in its raw form.
As we know, Chrome provides a raw form, still not sure about Safari.
The two requests in the sense, one from Chrome and the same from Safari.
It may be possible to find the differences if any when the same request is placed by the two
Browsers.

So, after much trial and error, it turned out that requests to ANY api failed when the page had first loaded, but later requests passed. This included OPTIONS requests, which made it appear like a cors earror. I resolved the issue by adding retry logic to the initial request.
I used the p-retry with the default backoff pattern and up to 5 retries.
I still don't understand why this happened, so if anyone could add an explanation it would be greatly appreciated.
